Token getting called continuously while refreshing the browser
Stack:
Angular 17
Abp.io version 5.3
When I refresh the browser, from polyfill.ts, the token is getting called continuously. Not sure from where it is getting called.
I am not using angular from abp.io. I am just using it from backend but I have used some of the core packages from abp.io in angular.
Here it is calling token continuously.

I am not sure why and from where it is continuously calling the token.
This is in local without service worker:


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
